# Список всевозможных строк, как начальная, но с разным регистром

Tags: python

есть входная строка допустим 'abc', а может кто имеет идейку, как сделать генерацию случайного регистра букв и вывод этих вариантов - 'Abc', 'ABc', AbC и т.д.

Comment: 1. так вам нужна генерация одной случайной перестановки или список всех возможных перестановок? 2. начните с декомпозиции своей глобальной задачи на более мелкие подзадачи, и задавайте вопросы уже по этим подзадачам.

Comment: список всевозможных строк, как начальная, но с разным регистром

Answer (score 1):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##FcwxCgMhEEbh3lP8WAQHghDShU2Tm4jMJhN0FHVZcnqD/Xtf/Y1P0fucHU/Y8IrWp3Jyc2TMXhoyRNGCvtndti2xuk70MEBtosNZ679F1Lnoj1rXBtmRLysWAqfOiIQlyTUui/XI3MLgBdGcfw)

```
s = "aBc".lower()

for m in range(1<<len(s)):
  print("".join((c.upper() if m&(1<<i) else c) for i,c in enumerate(s)))
```

Или, возможно, чуть оптимальнее: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##JY2xCgIxEET7fMWSQjYQDsROzsbfEIsQ9nQ12YRcgufXR6PdwJt5k9/1nuTQ@wYnuOB@ntmCn0J6UUEzYst5RANLKsDWAwuQtEjFVULtzl6bq1KDRrc@By5ObjRcgQQ3Y44KIBeWilpPj8SC2ICXX38XgcJKEP4H0QbbhuM76/0D):

```
x = [(1<<i, c.lower(), c.upper()) for i,c in enumerate("aBc")]

for mask in range(1<<len(x)):
  print("".join((u if mask&m else l) for m,l,u in x))
```

```
abc
Abc
aBc
ABc
abC
AbC
aBC
ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##NYsxDsIwDAB3v8LKZCOUhQ2JhZ@g0AqjNrYcV7SvD2RgO@nu7IiX1kvvs@uKEpOH6tJQVlMPNNfnVgKg4Q3T414SwKyOO0r9SzoRlbzoZ3LiM5a8mQ1kHGUZZWO@Av4GqUEp5bdKpZ259y8)

```
from itertools import product

s = "aBc"

for x in product(*((c.lower(), c.upper()) for c in s)):
  print("".join(x))
```

```
abc
abC
aBc
aBC
Abc
AbC
ABc
ABC
```